# XMLHttpRequest passing [object%20Object]

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I have the below code:

```
var formData = {};
formData['client_exists'] = 1;
formData['client_id'] = 1234;
formData['subdata'] = subdata;
```

This builds up an object, subdata is a multidimensional array.

I then try to pass it off to my controller with the following:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),  self = this;
window.location = window.location.origin+'/'+formAction+'/' + formData;
```

Note that I cannot use the below format as it causes an encoding issue with the pdf generation

```
 $.ajax({
    type  : formMethod,
    url   : formAction,
    data  : formData,
    cache : false,
    success : function(data) {
    }
});
```

When it gets to my controller I only get an empty array as my formData is passed through as this in the url:

```
[object%20Object]
```

I cant't figure out how to pass this through correctly, If i use JSON.stringify -

`window.location = window.location.origin+'/'+formAction+'/?' + JSON.stringify(formData);`

i get the data through however it isn't in a usable format:

```
array:1 [▼
  "{"client_exists":1,"client_id":123,"subdata":" => array:1 [▼
    "{"something":"111","something_else":"222","something_more":"333"}" => ""
  ]
]
```

Is there a better way for me to pass this through or a way I can format it into a proper multidimensional array on the back-end (PHP)?

Comment: "Note that I cannot use ajax here" — The entire point of XMLHttpRequest is to let you do Ajax.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it a little clearer

Comment: I get `{"client_exists":1,"client_id":1234,"subdata":{"something":"111","something_else":"222","something_more":"333"}}` by using `JSON.stringify(formData)`

Comment: @Inuka did you do any decoding or formatting on the backend?

Comment: @JonnyFoley no nothing at all. I'll put the used code in jsFiddle. Your approach was quite right.

Comment: Turns out my `subdata` wasn't an array but an object and this is what was causing my issue

Comment: @JonnyFoley convert that into an array if you can and it'll get the above result i mentioned.